# Finding distinct sections in an image

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose you're given a `vector<vector<bool>>` (square region) where a 1 corresponds to a "filled" box.  Are there any methods to find whole regions in O(n) time?  For example, this vector will have two whole regions:

```
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: What are the "whole regions" in your example? What is n? Number of pixels?

Comment: Yes.  n in this case is 64, since the matrix is 8x8.  The whole regions are the regions that contain 1s.  Since the 1s are connected in 2 different places, there are 2 regions (i.e. you can connect diagonally).

Answer (score 3):

This is called 8-connected [region growing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_growing). It is a standard technique in image processing, you select a seed pixel and "grow". This can be done with [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) in linear time in the number of pixels:

- keep a queue with the fringe, put there the initial seed
- get an element from the queue call it current point and added to your "region" list
- push to the queue the neighbors of the current point that are one, never push to the queue a point that you've already pushed to the queue
- finish when the queue is empty.

The region list contains a region, set that to zero. Find another seed and run again, until you can't find seeds.

Comment: What is the initial seed in this case?  Is it just any pixel (presumably the first one)?

Comment: The first location where you find a 1.

Comment: I added a link to BFS in Wikipedia, the fringe is the Q in the pseudo code they present ther.

Comment: So can you elaborate on how to accomplish this in linear time?

Comment: Also, why do I need a separate "region list" and not just a count?  How do I "find another seed" without iterating in such a way that exceeds linear (while running the BFS)?

Comment: You need them in the list so you can zero out the counted region and invoke BFS again on another seed. It is linear because a given location will at most be in the fringe (queue) once. After you find one seed and finish BFS, you keep going from the location you found the seed, you will only need to traverse the image once.

Comment: But throughout that traversal if I'm doing BFS, doesn't this mean it's not O(n)?

Comment: That BFS advances you on the traversal. Because you're zeroing out at the end of BFS.

Comment: Don't I have to construct a visited array of the same size?  Wouldn't this violate O(n)?

Comment: You can construct a visited data structure of size n and determine membership in constant time.

Comment: How do you construct the structure in constant time?

Comment: You construct the data structure in O(n) time and determine membership in constant time